# GAP code related to supersoluble abnormal subgroups

Tags: gap, computer-algebra-systems

The property I want to check is whether there exists a finite non-supersoluble group $G$ which admits a triple factorisation $G=AB=AC=BC$, where $A, B, C$ are abnormal supersoluble subgroups of $G$. (A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called abnormal if for all $x \in G$ we have $x \in \langle H, H^x \rangle$.)

I have begun testing for this property with the following GAP routines:

```
#Checks if g=hk
IsProductOf:=function(g,h,k)
if Order(g)*Order(Intersection(h,k)) = Order(h)*Order(k) then
  return true;
fi;
return false;
end;;

#Checks if the subgroup h is abnormal in the group g
IsAbnormalSubgroup:=function(g,h)
local norm, y, closure;
if not IsSubset(h,Centralizer(g,h)) then 
  return false;
fi;
norm:=Normalizer(g,h);
if Order(norm)>Order(h) then
  return false;
fi;
for y in RightTransversal(g,h) do
  closure:=ClosureGroup(h,ConjugateGroup(h,y));
    if not ForAll(TrivialSubgroup(g),x->x*y in closure) then
      return false;
    fi;
od;
return true;
end;;
```

and

```
# Checks whether the group g can be written as a product g=ab where a, b 
# are abnormal supersoluble subgroups of g, and whether g has at least three conjugacy
# classes of such subgroups
IsCandidateGroup:=function(g)
local list, a, b, brep, r, reps, i, j;
list:=Filtered(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g),Representative),
                    x->IsSupersolvableGroup(x) and IsAbnormalSubgroup(g,x));
if Size(list)<3 then
  return false;
fi;
for i in [1..Length(list)] do
a:=list[i]; 
  for j in [i+1..Length(list)] do
    brep:=list[j];  
    reps:=List(DoubleCosetRepsAndSizes(g,brep,a),x->x[1]);
      for r in reps do
        b:=brep^r;
          if IsProductOf(g,a,b) then
             return true;
          fi;
      od;
  od;
od;
return false;
end;;
```

Next,

```
test:=function(g)
local i, j, k, list, h, m, n, mrep, nrep, reps, r, s, Reps;
list:=Filtered(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g),Representative),
                    x->IsSupersolvableGroup(x) and IsAbnormalSubgroup(g,x));
for i in [1..Length(list)] do
h:=list[i];
  for j in [i+1..Length(list)] do
  mrep:=list[j];
  reps:=List(DoubleCosetRepsAndSizes(g,mrep,h),x->x[1]);
    for r in reps do
    m:=mrep^r;
      if IsProductOf(g,h,m) then
        for k in [j+1..Length(list)] do
        nrep:=list[k];
        Reps:=List(DoubleCosetRepsAndSizes(g,Normalizer(h,m),nrep),x->x[1]);
          for s in Reps do
          n:=nrep^s;
            if IsProductOf(g,h,n) and IsProductOf(g,m,n) then
              return true;
            fi;
          od;
        od;
      fi;
    od;
  od;
od;
return false;
end;;
```

Perhaps someone could suggest some concrete code to improve efficiency?

---

I have updated the code to account for suggestions and have simplified things in a couple of places, although I am not totally sure that the `test` function is correct.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to indent the code so that the structure is easier understood when looking at it. (I will comment on the question once that is done.)

Comment: I am not really sure what the correct format is for indenting code so I've done what makes sense to me. It should look a little better now. Also, I could put in an extra paragraph explaining what each bit aims for if you think that would help.

Comment: Also, just in case it is of any interest: this is problem 19.100 in the Kourovka notebook (p. 154 in the latest edition). Actually, the problem asks if whenever $G$ admits such a triple factorisation then $G$ is itself supersoluble, so my code is basically searching for a counterexample.

Comment: @the_fox I took the liberty of updating indentation - usually, the body of loops and if statements is indented, but not `for ... od` and `if ... fi` themselves. You can see some indentation examples in the GAP library. They may vary from time to time (e.g. some authors also will indent the body of the function; I don't as it requires too much efforts, I think). I also used triple backticks to display the code - this markup now works here, so you don't have to indent it by 4 more spaces, when pasting to this site!

Comment: Ah, thanks! I think this looks better than what I did before.

Comment: @the_fox you may also want to organise your search by orders of the Small Groups Library, to avoid repeated expensive calling of `AllSmallGroups`, see e.g. https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups/index.html

Comment: It doesn't take that much time to create `grps:=AllSmallGroups([1..220],IsSupersolvableGroup,false,IsCandidateGroup,true);;`, so I don't mind it much if it takes a couple of minutes for GAP to do that. But obviously I would like to have the best possible code for the whole thing. Is your suggestion related to the snippet of code in the link directly below *Modular programming begins here*?

Comment: That snippet is the 1st version of the code, the episode then goes on to enhance it, make it more flexible and display the progress of testing - so maybe you may want some further versions down that page.

Comment: Another suggestion is to use tests (https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/04-testing/index.html) - your code evolves quickly and you want to make sure that every modification does not break it. In addition, are you using version control to track changes of your code locally, and just paste the new version of the code here?

Comment: If you use version control, you do not have to reproduce the _whole_ GAP package setup to make your code more robust and demonstratable - for example, you can have a simple setup like here https://github.com/sukru-yalcinkaya/unipoly. If you are interested, I have a template for such reproducible computational experiments at https://github.com/rse-standrewscs/gap-binder-template and will be happy to help (and GitHub is better suited for collaborative code development).

Comment: You can also speed up the code by making `SubgroupsOfInterest` an attribute (see  https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/06-attributes/index.html). Otherwise, you calculate it once for each group calling `IsCandidateGroup` in `AllSmallGroups`, and then call it again in the main search loop.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I will need some time to look at your various suggestions. Meanwhile, you are more than welcome to contribute anything you feel might improve the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few remarks on coding for speed. Nothing changes the algorithms fundamentally or uses new mathematical ideas:

```
IsAbnormalSubgroup:=function(g,h)
local norm, x;
norm:=Normalizer(g,h);
if Order(norm)>Order(h) then
  return false;
```

`Normalizer` is a comparatively expensive operation, while `Centralizer` is often much faster. It might (but that is something one would have to try out in examples) give a speedup to test first (before computing the normalizer) whether the centralizer gives anything new:

```
  if not IsSubset(h,Centralizer(g,h)) then return false;fi;
```

Next, you run through all elements of $G$:

```
for x in g do
  if not x  in ClosureGroup(h,ConjugateGroup(h,x)) then
```

Running through all elements will take a long time and since you call this from within loops you want to be as efficient as possible here. A first reduction would be to run instead through cosets of $h$, that is through  representatives of $h\cap g$.

```
  for x in RightTransversal(g,Intersection(g,h)) do
```

Even better would be to run over cosets of $N_g(h)$ first, and then test one representative of every coset of $g\cap h$ therein in a double loop.

```
  no:=Normalizer(g,h);  
  tra:=RightTransversal(no,Intersection(g,h));
  for x1 in RightTransversal(g,no) do
    clo:=ClosureGroup(h,ConjugateGroup(h,x1));
    if not ForAll(tra,x->x*x1 in clo) then ...
```

Next:

```
#Creates a list of all abnormal supersoluble subgroups of the group g
SubgroupsOfInterest:=function(g)
local list, h;
list:=[];
for h in AllSubgroups(g) do
  if [...]
    Append(list,[h]);
```

It would be faster to test only one representative in each conjugacy class. That is:

```
  for hcl in ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g) do
    h:=Representative(hcl);
    if [...]
      Append(list,AsList(hcl));
```

Aside, though not needed here any longer, instead of `Append(list,[h]);` use `Add(list,h);` as it does not create an unneccessary list.

In your test

```
  if IsAbnormalSubgroup(g,h) and IsSupersolvableGroup(h) then
```

I think testing supersolvability will typically be faster then testing abnormality (which needs a normalizer). So I would use:

```
  if IsSupersolvableGroup(h) and IsAbnormalSubgroup(g,h) then
```

instead since GAP does "lazy" left-to right evaluation, skipping parts that will not change the logical value.

```
# Checks whether the group g can be written as a product g=ab where a, b 
# are subgroups of interest, and whether g has at least three conjugacy
# classes of supersoluble abnormal subgroups
IsCandidateGroup:=function(g)
local list, a, b;
list:=Filtered(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g),Representative),
                    x->IsSupersolvableGroup(x) and IsAbnormalSubgroup(g,x));
if Size(list)<3 then
  return false;
fi;
for a in list do
  for b in SubgroupsOfInterest(g) do
    if ArePermutableSubgroups(g,a,b) and ClosureGroup(a,b)=g then
```

If the test for permutability is more expensive, it would be sufficient to run through subgroups `b` up to conjugacy by $N_G(a)$. You could do so by taking `b` only up to conjugacy (i.e. change `SubgroupsOfInterest`) and calculate representatives of the double cosets $N_G(b)\setminus G/N_G(a)$ and then run through conjugates $b^r$ for the representatives $r$. You can also move rge `Closure` test outside this new innermost loop

```
  for a in list do
    na:=Normalizer(G,a);
    for brep in SubgroupsOfInterestUpToConjugacy(g) do
      if ClosureGroup(a,brep)=g then
        reps:=List(DoubleCosetsRepsAndSizes(G,Normalizer(G,brep),na),x->x[1]);
        for r in reps do
          b:=brep^r;
          if ArePermutableSubs(g,a,b) then
```

In your main loop you have the same situation:

```
  for h in list do
    for k in subs do
      for j in subs do
```

You could run for `k` up to conjugacy by $N_G(h)$ and for `j` up to conjugacy by $N_{N_G(h)}(k)$.

```
        if ArePermutableSubgroups(g,h,k) and
           ArePermutableSubgroups(g,k,j) and
           ArePermutableSubgroups(g,h,j) then
          if ClosureGroup(h,k)=g and 
             ClosureGroup(k,j)=g and 
             ClosureGroup(h,j)=g then
```

Again I expect the `Closure` tests to be cheaper than the `IsPermutable` tests. So do them before. Even more, move tests that only involve `h` and `k` outside the inner `j` loop, so you avoid repeated testing.

All these changes together should give you one, maybe even two magnitudes of speedup.

As for a more systematic description of such techniques, there is an old book: Jon Louis Bentley, *Writing Efficient Programs*, Prentice Hall, 1982 that I found useful.

Comment: One question related to the fourth point. Instead of
```
for x in g do
  if not x  in ClosureGroup(h,ConjugateGroup(h,x)) then
 return false;
  fi;
od;
```
are you suggesting that I put 
```
for x in GeneratorsOfGroup(g) do
  if not IsSubset(ClosureGroup(h,h^x),g) then
 return false;
  fi;
od;
```
or something else?

Comment: @the_fox triple backticks does not work for inline code fragments - use single backticks here, for example `this is code in single backticks`.

Comment: Sorry for my silliness, but I don't understand this point. Putting `#Checks if the subgroup h is abnormal in the group g
IsAbnormalSubgroup:=function(g,h)
local norm, x;
if not IsSubset(h,Centralizer(g,h)) then 
  return false;
fi;
norm:=Normalizer(g,h);
if Order(norm)>Order(h) then
  return false;
fi;
if not IsSubset(ClosureGroup(h,h^x),g) then 
  return false;
fi;
return true;
end;;
` results in an error when trying e.g. `g=SymmetricGroup(4)` and `h=CarterSubgroup(s4)`.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I had overlooked that conjugacy is by the same element.. I've changed to a loop over cosets of $g\cap h$.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I hope the first two routines are ok now. By the way, using `SubgroupsOfInterest` now results in an error message: `SubgroupsOfInterest(s4);
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for IsSupersolvableGroup on 1 arguments at /Applications/gap-4.10.2/lib/methsel2.g:250 called from
IsSupersolvableGroup( h ) at *stdin*:112 called from
<function "SubgroupsOfInterest">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:118
type quit; to quit to outer loop
brk> `

Comment: There was a similar error in an unrelated context (but again related to `IsSupersolvableGroup`). Try the following: `gap> LoadPackage("grpconst");;
gap> grps:=ConstructAllGroups(3^3*7^3);;
gap> for g in grps do
> Print(IsSupersolvableGroup(g),"\n");
> od;
`

Comment: `grpconst` returns a list whose entries might be lists again -- thus the second error. I cannot reproduce the first one in 4.11: `cl:=List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(SymmetricGroup(4)),Representative);;` and `List(cl,IsSupersolvableGroup);` works fine.

Comment: Yes, that works fine for me as well, as expected. Does calling `SubgroupsOfInterest` with the group of your choice work for you though?

Comment: I think I've found the mistake. It needs `for hcl in ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g) do` instead of `for hcl in ConjugacyClasses(g) do`.

Comment: Yes it does -- thank you.

Comment: @ahulpke I've noticed that ``` for code in the body of the answer now works for code fragments, just like on GitHub. This is indeed the change made on all StackExchange sites, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark. Finally no need to indent each line by 4 spaces!